# Translation of eigenvalue and its bound

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, riemannian-geometry, laplacian

Picture below is from  *[AN UPPER BOUND TO THE SPECTRUM OF $\Delta$ ON A MANIFOLD OF NEGATIVE CURVATURE](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214429509)* .

First, how to get (6) from (5)  ?  The (6) implies $f^{old}=f^{new}\sqrt{g}$. But I can't get it from $f'^{~new}=\sqrt{g}f'^{~old}$. Because $\sqrt{g}$  and $f$
are functions of $r$. Then integrate them , there will be not $f^{old}=f^{new}\sqrt{g}$ .

Second, How to get (7) from (4) ?

Thanks for any help.

> [image]
>
> [image]